# WooCommerce: Add class names to pagination items

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, bootstrap-4

To use Boostrap 4 classes, I want to add some class names to the WooCommerce pagination.
Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do so.

I've checked the `pagination.php`. It gives me the following code:

```
$total   = isset( $total ) ? $total : wc_get_loop_prop( 'total_pages' );
$current = isset( $current ) ? $current : wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' );
$base    = isset( $base ) ? $base : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
$format  = isset( $format ) ? $format : '';

if ( $total <= 1 ) {
    return;
}
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
            'base'         => $base,
            'format'       => $format,
            'add_args'     => false,
            'current'      => max( 1, $current ),
            'total'        => $total,
            'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
            'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
            'type'         => 'list',
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 3,
        ) ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

But the output is something like this:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
        <li><span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="/link/">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="/link/">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="/link/">4</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="/link/">5</a></li>
        <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="/link/">&rarr;</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, the class `page-numbers` isn't part of the `paginate_links` array. 
So I guess I couldn't change it in the file.

Is there any hook I can use to add classes to the `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<a>` element?

This is the structure I try to replicate (Bootstrap 4):

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retrieve paginated link for archive post pages.

- [`paginate_links( string|array $args = '' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/)

---

The template file to edit

- `loop/pagination.php`
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/loop/pagination.php

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php`.

---

So to obtain the desired result, you can apply the following

Replace

```php
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
    echo paginate_links(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_pagination_args',
            array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'base'      => $base,
                'format'    => $format,
                'add_args'  => false,
                'current'   => max( 1, $current ),
                'total'     => $total,
                'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                'type'      => 'list',
                'end_size'  => 3,
                'mid_size'  => 3,
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
</nav>
```

With

```php
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <?php
    $paginate_links =  paginate_links(
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args',
            array(
                'base'         => $base,
                'format'       => $format,
                'add_args'     => false,            
                'current'      => max( 1, $current ),
                'total'        => $total,
                'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
                'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
                'type'         => 'array',
                'end_size'     => 3,
                'mid_size'     => 3,
            ) 
        )
    );

         
    if ( is_array( $paginate_links ) ) {
    ?>
        <ul class="pagination">
        <?php 
        foreach ($paginate_links as $paginate_link) {
        ?>
            
            <li class="page-item">
                <?php
                $paginate_link = str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $paginate_link );
                echo wp_kses_post($paginate_link)
                ?>
            </li>
                
        <?php
        }
        ?>  
        </ul>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</nav>
```

---

Result:

```php
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><span class="page-link current">1</span></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="next page-link" href="#">→</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```